# Proof of triangle inequality for complex numbers in Baby Rudin, 2nd ed.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In the second edition of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* he states,

"If $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers, then $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$."

In the proof of this statement, he starts with,

> Put $$\lambda = \frac{|x+y|}{x+y}.$$
>
> Then, multiplying by $x+y$ and using Theorem 1.49b ($|xy|=|x||y|$), we
>   see that $|\lambda|=1$.

I assume that he concludes $|\lambda|=1$ as follows:

If we multiply by $x+y$ we have $(x+y)\lambda=|x+y|$. If I take absolute values on both sides, then by theorem 1.49b, $$|(x+y)\lambda|=|x+y||\lambda|,$$ and on the RHS, $$|(|x+y|)|=|x+y|.$$ Hence, $$|x+y||\lambda|=|x+y|,$$ and so $|\lambda|=1$.

My questions are:

1. When we multiply by $x+y$, we have that $(x+y)\lambda$ (a complex number) equals $|x+y|$ (a scalar). How is this so? I'm just a bit confused by what I see here. In my logic above I took the absolute value of both sides of an equality where, if I'm not mistaken, the LHS is complex and the RHS is strictly real.
2. Is it valid to take the absolute value of $|x+y|$ and conclude that it equals $|x+y|$? I assume so but want to confirm my logic.

Comment: **1.** The equality is only valid for *one* particular $\lambda$ which is in fact defined by that equality. **2.** $\,|a|=a\,$ by definition for any non-negative real $\,a\,$. With $\,a=|x+y|\,$ you get $\,|(|x+y|)|=|x+y|\,$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is also a complex number and multiplication of two complex numbers can be a real number(i.e. $(1-i)(1+i)=2$).

Comment: 1) Why not?  If $z = 2- 3i$ and $\gamma = -4 -6i$ we get $z\gamma = 10$ which is *both* a real number and a complex number. You are correct the that RHS is strictly real but the left hand side is not strictly unreal 2) If $|x+y| = c$ then $c\in \mathbb R$ and $c \ge 0$.  So $|c|=[ (c + 0i)(c-0i)]^{\frac 12}=(c^2)^{\frac 12} = c$.  SO yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we multiply by x+y, we have that (x+y)λ (a complex number) equals
>   |x+y| (a scalar). How is this so? I'm just a bit confused by what I
>   see here. In my logic above I took the absolute value of both sides of
>   an equality where, if I'm not mistaken, the LHS is complex and the RHS
>   is strictly real.

$\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$.

So LHS is complex that *could* be real.  And RHS is complex that *must* be real (and non-negative).

That is not an issue.  $\lambda$ was defined in a particular way and as a result we can conclude  that $(x+y)\lambda = |x+y|\in \mathbb R^+ $.    There was no reason to believe that *couldn't* happen so we shouldn't be surprised that it did.

We can't expect it of two *arbitrary* complex numbers but as $\lambda$ was *defined* by $x+y$ there are certainly not arbitrary.

In other words....  a strictly real number is complex, and a complex number *could* be strictly real if it was defined to be strictly real.

> Is it valid to take the absolute value of |x+y| and conclude that it
>   equals |x+y|? I assume so but want to confirm my logic.

Yes.

$|x+y| = c$ and $c\ge 0$.  $(c^2)^{\frac 12}$ is a distinct positive real number $b$ so that $b^2 = c^2$.  As $c^2 = c^2$ we can conclude that $(c^2)^{\frac 12} = c$ for all $c\in \mathbb R; c \ge 0$.

Also $c = c+0i = c-0i$ so $c = \overline c$.

So $|c| = (c\overline c)^{\frac 12} = (c^2)^{\frac 12}= c$ for all $c \ge 0$ and .... $|x+y| \ge 0$>

....

or in other words.

Let $x\in \mathbb R$.

If $x \ge  0$ then $|x|= (x\overline x)^{\frac 12} = =[(x + 0i)(x-0i)]^{\frac 12}=(x^2)^{\frac 12}$.  As $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 = x^2, $(x^2)^{\frac 12} = x$.

So $|x| = x$ if $x$ is real and $x \ge 0$.

If $x < 0$ then $|x|= (x\overline x)^{\frac 12} = =[(x + 0i)(x-0i)]^{\frac 12}=(x^2)^{\frac 12}$.  As $-x > 0$ and $(-x)^2 = x^2, $(x^2)^{\frac 12} = -x$

So $|x| = - x$ if $x$ is real and $x < 0$.

So for real numbers the new-fangled complex absolute value is the same old real absolute value we know and love.

As $|x+y|$ is real and $|x+y| \ge 0$ we have $||x+y|| = |x+y|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
|x + y| \leq |x| + |y| &\iff |x + y|^2 \leq (|x| + |y|)^2 \\
&\iff (x + y)\overline{(x + y)}   \leq |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2 \\
\text{Note: }(x + y)\overline{(x + y)}  &= (x + y)(\overline{x} + \overline{y}) \\
&= x \cdot \overline{x} + \overline{x} \cdot y + x \cdot \overline{y} + y \cdot \overline{y} \\ &= |x|^2 + (\overline{x} \cdot y) + \overline{(\overline{x} \cdot y)} + |y|^2 \\
&= |x|^2 + 2Re(\overline{x} \cdot y) + |y|^2 \\
&\leq |x|^2 + 2 |\overline{x}||y| + |y|^2  \\
&= |x|^2 + 2 |x||y| + |y|^2
\end{align*}
$$
Which completes the proof.